# .NET XMLDocument Encoding issue

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, xmldocument

I'm facing a quite specific problem at the moment. I'm storing some data in a XMLDocument and saves it on the HDD. They are looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Units>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Kilogramm</Name>
      <ShortName>Kg</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Flasche(n)</Name>
      <ShortName>Fl</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Stück</Name>
      <ShortName>St</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Beutel</Name>
      <ShortName>Btl</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Schale</Name>
      <ShortName>Sch</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Kiste</Name>
      <ShortName>Ki</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Meter</Name>
      <ShortName>m</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Stunde(n)</Name>
      <ShortName>h</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Glas</Name>
      <ShortName>Gl</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Portion</Name>
      <ShortName>Port</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Dose</Name>
      <ShortName>Do</ShortName>
    </Unit>
    <Unit>
      <Name>Paket</Name>
      <ShortName>Pa</ShortName>
    </Unit>
  </Units>
</Settings>
```

I'm Loading the file via XMLDocument.Load() and saveing it with XMLDocument.Save().
But now I saved the file from an old PC and now I got an exception on the special characters (ä,ö,ü), after saving and reloading.
In fact viewing the files in Notepad shows no differences, but viewing on hex there are some! How is this possible?

Comment: If your problem is quite specific, then perhaps you could edit your question to use a more specific title? There must be 100,000 questions on [so] which dould accurately use the title ".NET XmlDocument".

Comment: Check documents encoding (just open with **Notepad** and perform **Save As** to see what's encoding it presents).

Comment: @Adriano: The right file has UTF-8 as expected, the other one ANSI. But why are they different with the same code?

Comment: You can write in you XML file encoding="utf-8" but write it as ANSI, for example. I don't know why they're different (it may depends, but **I'm guessing**, the default encoding used in an old editor).

Comment: Maybe it can help you a little:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/4074648/1197361

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this [extensionmethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) to set the decoding prior to saving.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the XmlDeclaration if it exists, creates a new if not.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlDocument"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static XmlDeclaration GetOrCreateXmlDeclaration(this XmlDocument xmlDocument)
{
    XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = null;
    if (xmlDocument.HasChildNodes)
        xmlDeclaration = xmlDocument.FirstChild as XmlDeclaration;

    if (xmlDeclaration != null)
        return xmlDeclaration;
    //Create an XML declaration. 
    xmlDeclaration = xmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);

    //Add the new node to the document.
    XmlElement root = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;
    xmlDocument.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
    return xmlDeclaration;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = xmlDocument.GetOrCreateXmlDeclaration();
xmlDeclaration.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8.WebName;
xmlDocument.Save(@"filename");
```

Comment: Using the same code, for me the `xmlDocument.InsertBerfore()` throws this exception: `cannot insert the node in the specified location`. My xml file is just a regular xml document.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly add the declaration

```
var Doc = new XmlDocument();
Doc.AppendChild(Doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
var productsNode = Doc.AppendChild(Doc.CreateElement("products"));
//do other stuff
```