# Could not create XMLStreamReader in xtest (HIEOS)

Tags: c#, java, xml

While accessing the xtest (testplan.xml) in HIEOS, through . Am getting the following error.

```
FatalError (step null) : Could not create XMLStreamReader (in Util.parse_xml()) from string: o;?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

How to resolve it ?

**Note:** I've modified the XML values using C#.NET; before modification the xtest is working fine. What could be the reason?

Additional Details: I have tested the same XML file with the following C# code.

```
XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(@"D:\hieos-1.2\xtest\test\scripts\testdata\trial3\submit\testplan.xml");
XmlValidatingReader r = new XmlValidatingReader(tr);
r.ValidationType = ValidationType.None;
try
{
    while (r.Read()) ;
}
catch (XmlException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine("Exception object Line, pos: (" + e.LineNumber + "," + e.LinePosition + ")");
    Console.WriteLine("Exception source URI: (" + e.SourceUri + ")");
    Console.WriteLine("XmlReader Line, pos: (" + tr.LineNumber + "," + tr.LinePosition + ")");
}
```

No Exception caused. I think `XMLStreamReader` checks for something else in the XML file.

The content of my XML file is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestPlan>
<Test>vsmallpnr/submit</Test>
 <TestStep id="submit_docs">
    <NewPatientId/>
    <ExpectedStatus>Success</ExpectedStatus>
    <ProvideAndRegisterTransaction>
        <XDSb/>
    <AssignUuids/>
        <MetadataFile>sor.xml</MetadataFile>
        <Document id="Document01">test_pdf_doc.pdf</Document>
        <Document id="Document02">test_hitsp_c32.xml</Document>
    <Document id="Document03">test_txt_doc.txt</Document>
    <Document id="Document04">test_txt_doc.txt</Document>
    <Document id="Document05">test_txt_doc.txt</Document>
    </ProvideAndRegisterTransaction>
</TestStep>
<TestStep id="reset_patient_id">
    <NewPatientId/>
</TestStep>
```

**Solution:**
I have changed the XML save method using the [UTF-8 Encoding.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074648/when-saving-an-xmldocument-it-ignores-the-encoding-in-the-xmldeclaration-utf8) Then the error is resolved. Thanks to everyone for your support.

Comment: Why the C# *and* Java tags?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I have modified the XML content using C#. It is not showing any exception. (Code attached). It is showing the error for java.

Comment: I guess you are reading the wrong file in xtest. Have a close look at the error message. It says it could not create a reader from the following string: `o;?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Note the `o;?` at the beginning. This certainly doesn't belong there and doesn't exist in the file you showed here.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Yes, You got my problem. I am seeing some `o;?` in my error message, where as the XML file doesn't consist it. So I need some Java Experts answer, why it is coming and from where to solve this issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. Java doesn't randomly insert stuff into the files it reads. There are two possible reasons I can think of: (1) You are reading the wrong file. (2) The file has another encoding as the one expected by xtest

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No chance for first option, because the file name is by default.The second option is also impossible, because before modifying the value with C# code, it was working :(

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy c# might changed your encoding...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName, After [Encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074648/when-saving-an-xmldocument-it-ignores-the-encoding-in-the-xmldeclaration-utf8) the program is working fine. Thanks to all.

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy let me right it in my answer so you can accept it, or write it yourself in an answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem of the `XMLStreamReader` in xtest is due to encoding technique of C#.

Once the [encoding technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074648/when-saving-an-xmldocument-it-ignores-the-encoding-in-the-xmldeclaration-utf8) for the C# code is changed, then the error is resolved.

```
using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\hieos-1.2\xtest\test\scripts\testdata\trial3\submit\testplan.xml", false, Encoding.Default))
{                    
    xmlDoc.Save(sw);
 }
```

If we didn't mention the encoding type, it is creating the white-space in the `XMLDocument` before the actual content. That is the reason, Xtest (Java) is throwing the XMLStreamReader error.

Answer (score 0):

When loading Xml with `XmlWriter` or `StreamWriter` it is important to mention the Encoding you need to the xml. the fact that you loaded a UTF-8 xml does not mean a UTF-8 xml is going to be saved. use:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("myRoot");
doc.AppendChild(root);
root.InnerText = "myInnerText";
using(TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt", false, Encoding.UTF8)) //Set encoding
{
    doc.Save(sw);
}
```

Comment: I want resolution in Java. The C# code works fine. Am getting the Error in Java (xtest).

Comment: @DineshkumarPonnusamy well, then your question is way not understanable

Comment: Please check the above discussion.